# Call a method on Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, methods

I want to make this code work on c# code behind. I know in C something similar can be done, but can it be done here?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bar.Text = "Updating Information";
    InsertData();
    Bar.Text = "Information Updated";
}


protected void InsertData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //loops and statements
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First, you're not passing the expected parameters:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bar.Text = "Updating Information";
    InsertData(sender, e);
    Bar.Text = "Information Updated";
}


protected void InsertData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //loops and statements
}
```

Second, this looks like ASP.NET Web Forms. The changes to the Text property of your control will not update the UI. To understand why, you have to understand what's really going on outside the bounds of the actual code you write. ASP.NET WebForms have a very high degree of "inversion of control"; your code lives to serve the ASP engine resident in the IIS webserver, and has very little ultimate control over when it runs (or even when it *exists*).

This has two major consequences for you; first, the amount of state information retained by the server about each client asking for pages from it is very low; ideally, no state is saved (but realistically the server must usually keep track of some "session state", especially for secured web apps requiring a login). In fact, your codebehind class only lives as long as it takes to render a page; after that, the class (and any state data it was trying to store in memory) are disposed of and garbage-collected.

Second, and more importantly for you, anything done in the codebehind to render the next requested page will not result in real-time updates for the client; everything your code does in the codebehind, from Page_Load to Page_OnPreRender, is performed before a single bit of the resulting HTML is sent back to the client. The upshot is that changing the value of a control on the form several times during the execution of codebehind event handlers has zero bearing on what the client sees, unless you specifically set up additional communication with the client. The updating of Bar.Text before calling InsertData() will not cause the client to see the message "Updating Information". All the client will ever see is "Information Updated", because that is the text of the control as of when the page is finally rendered into HTML, *after* all your event handlers execute.

Problems like these are typically resolved with asynchronous architectures such as AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And XML). JavaScript's level of control over the rendered page in the browser window rivals that of a WinForms application (enough that you can program simple games with HTML as your UI using only client-side JavaScript), and there are methods and objects JavaScript can use to send requests for data to your server. So, to keep the user's displayed page responsive during this insert operation, you could employ these tricks. You'd have a button on your page that, instead of triggering a full postback of the entire page, would instead trigger a Javascript method on the client that would send a web service request to your server, and also update the value of your Bar UI control text with the status "Updating Information". The server would perform an action (your "InsertData()" call) and then respond to the client's browser, which would trigger a second JavaScript method that would update the status again with "Information Updated".

As an aside, it is in fact possible to create entire web applications using this Javascript-based "service-oriented architecture" for all content updates, where only one initial HTML page is ever served to the client browser, and all further changes to that page's layout, content and behavior is controlled by JavaScript updating the one page's DOM based on data received from web service calls. Such architecture of a website has its downsides, but also some big advantages.

Comment: -1: Why pass sender and e? Also, pages aren't "RESTful"? They're stateless. The term "RESTFul" has nothing to do with a "resting state", which doesn't exist in any case.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Because the method is expecting it. It's not my place to question why; the code of the handler was omitted, but it could conceivably use them. I edited to remove the restful bit and emphasize stateless.

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice that.

Comment: To your point, however, it's extremely unlikely either of these will be needed. The sender of a Page_Load event handler is always the control (because the control raises its own events), and EventArgs as it is contains no useful properties.

Comment: @KeithS will you please explain this statement "**Such architecture of a website has its downsides, but also some big advantages.**". What are the disadvantages of using javaScript DOM updates and Ajax calls?
+1 for the good introduction to asp.net page rendering.

Comment: Well, first, such a site wouldn't behave nicely with the browser's back button; since everything you get is all technically the same page, clicking back will take you to whichever page you were on before the landing page, no matter how many hours you'd spent inside the site. Second, this is a *lot* of code that needs to run client-side, in an environment you cannot control, and so security-dependent things need to be handled on the server side, possibly fouling up the model of one fully dynamic page. You also get very little for free, unless you have a framework with the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bar.Text = "Updating Information";
InsertData(this, EventArgs.Empty);
Bar.Text = "Information Updated";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `InsertData()` method, since you are calling it with no parameters.

```
protected void InsertData()
    {
      //loops and statements
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to know the sender or pass EventArgs? You could simple redefine the InsertData Method as

```
protected void InsertData()
{
  //loops and statements
}
```

and then call the method via

```
Bar.Text = "Updating Information";
InsertData();
Bar.Text = "Information Updated";
```